# Stop SQL Server Management studio from breaking my view

Tags: sql, view, format, ssms

I have a view that is working completely fine, and looks roughly as follows:

```
 WITH xxx AS ( ... ),
      yyy AS ( SELECT ... FROM xxx )

 SELECT ... FROM yyy
```

Pretty straightforward, and it has been working great.  However, a situation has arisen and I need to make a very small change to `xxx` .  I go into the view editor, make the small change to xxx, but when I save/execute, suddenly Server Management Studio's auto format takes over and decides to change my view to this:

```
 WITH yyy AS ( SELECT ... FROM xxx),
      xxx AS ( ... )

 SELECT ... FROM yyy
```

Basically it switches the first and second parts of my WITH statement, for no apparent reason!  I've tried scripting the view to a new query, making the change there and recreating it, and it does the same thing.

Is there a way to turn off the auto formatting!?  Any other suggestions!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to win is to stop using the view designer entirely.

You have to make a choice

- either you *do* care about the layout of the code within the view - in which case you will write it yourself in the query editor window, or,
- you treat the view as entirely generated by the view designer, in which case you need to ignore what it ends up looking like.

Comment: Good code formatting is important. View designers makes it unrecognizable.

Comment: Is there another way to enter code for the view besides using the designer's code window?

Comment: Yes, you can create views, stored procedures and tables all in T-SQL from the Query Window. Sadly, unless you retain your own repo of well-organized idempotent scripts, you will be forever re-formatting the code SQL gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this option:

[image]

Use this instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply stop auto formatting by adding any valid SQL syntax that the visual designer doesn't recognize:

- UNION
- FOR XML PATH
- ...

For example, add `AND (SELECT NULL FOR XML PATH) IS NOT NULL` at the end of your WHERE criteria